# Adding subview to UITableView with autolayout doesn't set its frame

Tags: uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I am using the following code to add a overlay view to a view:

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] init];
overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:overlayView];

overlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(overlayView);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[overlayView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[overlayView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

If I place this code in the `viewDidLoad` method of a `UIViewController` it works fine. However, if I do the same in a `UITableViewController` the overlay view gets a zero frame.

I have inspected the view and I can se the constraints do get added correctly and they are active. But for som reason they seem to be ignored.

I don't get any error or warning.

What am I missing here?

PS: I know I can instantiate the overlay view with `self.view.bounds` as frame, and it works. However, I need to use autolayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suspect it's because the UITableView is a UIScrollView and auto layout has a few caveats when working with views that establish their own bounds systems (such as the scroll view or table view).

The constraints set on the overlay view are such that it is constrained to the top, right, bottom, and left edges of the scroll view, and thus to the content area of the scroll view rather than the scroll view's frame.

See
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html 
and [Auto Layout Guide: Working with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html):

> Constraints between the edges or margins of the scroll view and its
>   content attach to the scroll view’s content area.

Instead of constraining overlay view to the content area, constrain it to the scroll view's frame instead. According to the above references, this can be done either by constraining overlay view's width/height to the scroll view, or by constraining the overlay view to a view outside of the scroll view.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was something like this. I did solve it in other way, but I would have preferred to have been able to use autolayout.

Comment: In iOS 11 you can use the frameLayoutGuide property of the table view.