# iOS Swift Constraints not working, subview of UITableView disappears when translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I've dealt with programmatically creating constraints, but something isn't working this time and I can't figure out what it is.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageview = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "dollarsign"))
    //imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    imageview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 0.10)
    self.view.addSubview(imageview)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imageview)
    
    imageview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    imageview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    
    imageview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320).isActive = true
    imageview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 480).isActive = true
```

When `imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` is commented out, the image view shows up and is just positioned at (0,0) with it's natural width,height.

[image: view controller with image showing]

but I don't want it to automatically create constraints for me, so when I uncomment `imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` to let my programmatic constraints kick in... then the UIImageView disappears:

[image: view controller but image has disappeared]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I don't understand it, but for some reason, when I let the constraints take control, it is positioning it at -320,-480 even though I've created constraints to connect it to the trailing and bottom anchors.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print("image view frame: \(imageview.frame)")
}
```

> image view frame: (-320.0, -480.0, 320.0, 480.0)

Comment: With your constraints, the image view should not be at (0, 0). Shouldn't it be at the bottom right? Why did you expect it to be at (0, 0)? And I cannot reproduce the behaviour. The image view appears at the bottom right when I uncomment `= false`. Try reproducing this in a fresh new project.

Comment: Oh wait, you are using a table view that shows a bunch of things, so you actually need to scroll down a bit before you actually see the "bottom right". Try that.

Comment: @kenny Wyland Remove width/height constraint and give top bottom constraint.

Comment: @Sweeper I don't want it to at 0,0, but that's where it normally defaults to without constraints. I want the image to be pegged to the bottom and right, which it why I'm setting a bottom and trailing constraint. I don't want it constrained to the top of the view. The issue is that the image view disappears when I uncomment the `= false`.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956065/adding-subview-to-uitableview-with-autolayout-doesnt-set-its-frame). It's apparently because you are adding it as a subview of `UITableView`. According to that post, you should constrain to `self.tableView.frameLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor` and `self.tableView.frameLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` instead. Is that what you want?

Comment: Is that a TableViewController? if so, the main view is then your table view and if you add subview to it you're gonna get weird behavior.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes! That did it! `self.tableView.frameLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor` worked. Can you please post that as a full answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: I would rather close it as a duplicate as the linked question. But I had initially voted to close as no-repro, so I can’t vote again.

Answer (score 1):

The code should work fine with

`imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false.`

That's what you should always do when creating constraints programmatically. Only reason it is not working must be because, some view is on top of your ImageView and you are not seeing it. May be you could debug view hierarchy.

**If your base controller is UITableViewController it's another story.**

You need to add a **backgroundView** to the tableview and then add UIImageView in it. Below is the example:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var imageview:UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        imageview = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test"))
        imageview.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        
        imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        imageview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 0.10)
        let bgView = UIView(frame: self.tableView.bounds)
        self.tableView.backgroundView = bgView
        bgView.addSubview(imageview)
        bgView.bringSubviewToFront(imageview)
        
        imageview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        imageview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320).isActive = true
        imageview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 480).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using a UITableViewController If I use the background view, then my ImageView shows up behind the cells and is obscured by it. And I don't want to set the background color of the cells to Clear because I want that slight grey/blue color for the section headers so the background color of the tableview is grey/blue. If the cells are clear, then the grey/blue will show through them as well.

Answer (score 1):

My original code would have worked if my `self.view` were just a `UIView`, but it was a `UITableView` and since a `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView` its layout anchors are different.

I needed to my constraint anchors to `self.tableView.frameLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor` and `self.tableView.frameLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` and then it worked perfectly.